# Install an Electron app without code sign and Smart Screen

Tags: electron-builder

I need some information ,i need to install a Electron app in another computer but i have the problem with the Smart Screen on Windows because the app isn't sign.
The question is if can i install my Electron app without the Smart Screen without paying for code sign ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the "Windows Defender Smartscreen" click the "more info" link then the "Run anyway" button.

[image]